# Substantial difference between database size under MySQL and actual size on disk

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mariadb

When I check the size of my databases under MySQL I get this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name",  sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 /  1024 "Data Base Size in MB",  sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB"  FROM information_schema.TABLES  GROUP BY table_schema;
+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Data Base Name     | Data Base Size in MB | Free Space in MB |
+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| alfresco           |         245.75000000 |      34.00000000 |
| drupal             |         892.15625000 |     216.00000000 |
+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

When I check the size on the disk I get this:

```
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /var/lib/mysql/
317M    /var/lib/mysql/alfresco
1.4G    /var/lib/mysql/drupal
```

If I combine both used and free space given by Maria DB and compare it with disk figures I have the following:

```
alfresco: DB=279MB  DISK=317MB (+14%)
drupal: DB=1100MB   DISK=1433MB (+30%)
```

**Q: Is it normal to have that much overhead on the disk / Is there anything I can do to reduce it?**

FYI I thought running a mysql optimize would help ([using that command](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?108,201578,201578)), it did reduce the size of the databases, but didn't change the size of files on the disk.

**Additional info:**

```
server:             ubuntu server 10.04 LTS
DB server:          MariaDB
DB engine:          InnoDB v10 (for all tables)
Table collation:    utf8_general_ci
Nb Drupal tables:   416  (0.80MB overhead per table)
Nb Alfresco tables: 84   (0.45MB overhead per table)
```

Comment: All InnoDB tables? How many tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using InnoDB tables, the size of your ibdata files will grow over time. So, if you issue `DELETE` statement, your database size will reduce, but the ibdata file will remain the same (not reduce).

If you are not using `innodb_file_per_table` option, the only way to reclaim the space is by dumping the database and restoring from the dumpfile.

However, if you are using `innodb_file_per_table`, you can issue an

```
ALTER TABLE foo ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

on tables that grow too large to reclaim the disk space.

Comment: why doesn't the size of the ibdata files reduces if the  size of the database does?

Comment: It's apparently a 'design decision' made by developers of innodb, briefly explained in the comments of [this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1287). A similar [feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1341) was made quite a few years back, but nothing has been done about it. I don't agree with the design decision personally, but it is what it is.

Comment: why didn't optimise table reclaim space? or is that just "tidy" not "shrink"?

Comment: @gbn "For InnoDB tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE, which rebuilds the table to update index statistics and free unused space in the clustered index." [src](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) So yes, just a tidy. Same reason an `AlTER TABLE foo ENGINE=InnoDB` without `innodb_file_per_table=1` won't shrink ibdata.